# How do I get out of full-screen mode?

Tags: debian, gnome, libreoffice

I'm using LibreOffice 4.2.4.2 (Calc) in debian wheezy.  In an attempt to hide the window title bar I have enabled full-screen mode, which has hidden both the window title bar of Calc and the menu bar in GNOME. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> takes me in an out of full-screen mode, which seems to just remove the menu icons and restores them. It does not restore the title bar of the window nor the GNOME menu.

Restarting Libre Calc has no effect. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> also has no effect. Is this a feature or a bug? Either way, what's the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think I've found a fix; nuke my `~/.config/libreoffice/4` folder and never go into full-screen mode again, thereby fixing the problem [once and for all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxEMA.jpg).

Comment: I've since moved to OpenOffice and haven't had this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Although I use Win7 I´d imagine the same keys work.
From the Libre Office help files:

> In Writer and Calc, you can also use the shortcut keys Ctrl+Shift+J to
>   switch between the normal and full screen mode.
>
> You can still use shortcut keys in Full Screen mode, even though the
>   menus are unavailable. To open the View menu, press Alt+V.

Comment: That just brings up and disappears the window title, it doesn't bring back the gnome menu bar (equivalent of taskbar in windows)... I think this might be a bug.

Comment: Sorry it didn´t work in your set-up - Brian